# Is there a way to fill image within SVG using CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

Just like how CSS styles like fill, stroke being set via CSS, is there a way to set image (background-image) to an SVG element using CSS alone?
Some existing solutions have `<image>` tag within the `<svg>` element, but I don't want to have that since I'm using a third-party library that generates the SVG, so CSS seems to be a good alternative.

Update:
I would like to add a `background` to a specific `svg` element, not the whole SVG. Didn't realize that it wasn't mentioned in the actual question earlier.

Comment: `svg{background:url("whatever.jpg");}`

Comment: @paul-lebeau I don't think its a duplicate. This question is completely different from those.

Comment: Sorry. Reopened. I missed the "using CSS alone" bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way you can do what you want is to define your pattern fills in a separate SVG.  Then you can assign those predefined patterns via CSS.

Demo:

```css
.filled {
  fill: url(#image-fill);
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">

  <!-- image fills defined here in this hidden SVG -->
  <defs>
    <pattern id="image-fill"
             patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
      <image x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
             xlink:href="https://placekitten.com/400/400"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>

</svg>



<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <path class="filled" d="M 100,50 L 450,200 L 150,350 Z" stroke="grey"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add it via CSS. Run the snippet to see it work:

```css
svg{
  background: url("https://www.fillmurray.com/79/79");
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="160" viewBox="0 0 400 160">
  <circle cx="200" cy="80" r="30" fill="red" stroke="white" stroke-width="4"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: I've updated the question, did not realize that I missed the `SVG element` there. Thanks for your answer though.